# How to keep arrow functions small and readable in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions, readability

I completed a tutorial on how to make a Tetris game in-browser using JS and HTML/CSS, but I'm having trouble understanding if the author's coding practices for the JS portion are good, and if not, how they can be improved. For clarity, the code in question can be found here: https://github.com/kubowania/Tetris-Basic/blob/master/app.js

What I understand from reading this is that the author creates an arrow function that is run when all DOM content is loaded and all of the functionality for the game exists there. What I don't understand is why they just throw all of the variables, functions, and event listeners into that one function seemingly haphazardly. I think it's hard to follow and would like to learn how to improve it - what would be the best practice for something like this? Is there a way to declare the functions and variables elsewhere in the file or other JS files? Or am I incorrect and this is acceptable for JS?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about how the file starts with this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
```

It works fine, but is probably one of those things that grew over time.  (At least, often times I write this exact line of code with 2 or 3 lines in the event handler, and then a couple days later there's 100 things in it and its time to clean up a bit.)

> Or am I incorrect and this is totally acceptable for JS?

The language doesn't care.  Whether or not it's acceptable is up to you and the folks working on the same code.

> what would be the best-practice for something like this?

Breaking things up into modules is commonly done.  It seems to me that this code example is just that... an example.  Working with bundlers to handle modules is probably out of scope for a simple tutorial.  It's probably easier for folks taking this Udemy class to have this all in one place.